# SolverFactory.solve summary option

Tags: pyomo

Pyomo solver invocation can be achieved by command line usage or from a Python script.

How does the command line call with the summary flag

```
pyomo solve model.py input.dat --solver=glpk --summary
```

translate to e.g. the usage of a `SolverFactory` class in a Python script?

Specifically, in the following example, how can one specify a summary option?  Is it an (undocumented?) argument to `SolverFactory.solve`?

```py
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pyomo.environ

from model import model

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

instance = model.create_instance('input.dat')

results = opt.solve(instance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The --summary option is specific to the `pyomo` command. It is not a solver option. I believe all it really does is execute the line

```
pyomo.environ.display(instance)
```

after the solve, which you can easily add to your script. A more direct way of querying the solution is just to access the value of model variables or the objective by "evaluating" them. E.g.,

```
instance.some_objective()
instance.some_variable()
instance.some_indexed_variable[0]()
```

or

```
pyomo.environ.value(instance.some_objective)
pyomo.environ.value(instance.some_variable)
pyomo.environ.value(instance.some_indexed_variable)
```

I prefer the former, but the latter is more appropriate if you are accessing the values of immutable, indexed Param objects. Also, note that variables have a `.value` attribute that you can access directly (and update if you want to provide a warmstart).

Answer (score 0):

Per default the `--summary` command option stores a 'result' file in json format into the directory of your model.

You can achieve the same result by adding the following to your code:

```
results = opt.solve(instance, load_solutions=True)
results.write(filename='results.json', format='json')
```

or:

```
results = opt.solve(instance)
instance.solutions.store_to(results)
results.write(filename='results.json', format='json')
```